# java.io.IOException: Can't write react-native run-android failed

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

**FAILURE:** Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task `':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'`.

  > java.io.IOException: Can't write [/home/user/Desktop/pratap/react-projects/test/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/proguard/debug/0.jar] (Can't read [/root/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/25cd9e2eed8b822cb2ad78849b3b28bf/jars/classes.jar(;;;;;;;**.class)] (Duplicate jar entry [android/support/v4/app/INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy.class]))

I'm running `react-native run-android` command to run the app and getting above error I don't know what's going on with `java.io.IOException`

**I have tried:**

1. remove android > build folder and run again
2. run cd android && gradlew clean and then cd .. && react-native run-android
3. remove node_modules folder and reinstall it  by npm install

screenshot - 
[image]

GRADLE -

```
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

android {
    purgeBackgroundGeolocationDebugResources(applicationVariants)
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
     compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.localbroadcastmanager_localbroadcastmanager.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.appcompat_appcompat.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.swiperefreshlayout_swiperefreshlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.drawerlayout_drawerlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.print_print.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.versionedparcelable_versionedparcelable.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.interpolator_interpolator.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.fragment_fragment.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.documentfile_documentfile.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-utils.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.loader_loader.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.viewpager_viewpager.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.vectordrawable_vectordrawable-animated.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.slidingpanelayout_slidingpanelayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version'
        exclude 'META-INF/androidx.legacy_legacy-support-core-ui.version'
    }
    dexOptions {
      javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.smarttransitio"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release

        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':@react-native-mapbox-gl_maps')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-fetch')
    implementation project(':react-native-nfc-manager')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-timer')
    implementation project(':react-native-background-geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-keep-awake')
    implementation project(':react-native-smartwifi')
    implementation project(':react-native-smartnfc')
    implementation project(':react-native-imei')
    implementation project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    implementation project(':react-native-branch')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.9'
    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
    implementation project(':react-native-fused-location')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-shimmer')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-i18n')
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation(project(":react-native-device-info"), {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    })
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0"
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.59.9"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all implementation dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// [Added by react-native-background-geolocation] Purge debug sounds from release build.
def purgeBackgroundGeolocationDebugResources(applicationVariants) {
    if ((rootProject.ext.has("removeBackgroundGeolocationDebugSoundsInRelease")) && (rootProject.ext.removeBackgroundGeolocationDebugSoundsInRelease == false)) return
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
            println("[react-native-background-geolocation] Purging debug resources in release build")
            variant.mergeResources.doLast {
                delete(fileTree(dir: variant.mergeResources.outputDir, includes: ["raw_tslocationmanager*"]))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

React-native version - 0.59

Comment: I thini it is because the native dependencies use androidx. appcompat is the previous ser of libraries while material is from the new androidx

Comment: @cutiko I hava tried to remove 
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1'
and
 implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
but got no luck

Comment: Try to remove every Android dependency you add and leave only the RN default dependencies, then add one by one untill you find the problem

Comment: tried but got not luck again, I have updated the gradle code can you check again plz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try running 'jetifier' to migrate libraries to AndroidX if that is the case.(if there are native dependencies using AndroidX.)

1. npm install --save-dev jetifier
2. npx jetify
3. npx react-native run-android

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to run a **first** Terminal with : `npm start -- --reset-cache`

and then a **second** one with : `react-native run-android`